# File vs array, which one is faster?

Tags: c, arrays, performance, file

I made a program which read characters in a file, many times, in a loop.
If I don't care about memory usage, is storing all characters of the file in an array faster than accessing characters with fgetc ?

Comment: disk read/write access is slow compared to access memory!!

Comment: You should include in the question the exact pieces of code that you want to compare.

Comment: I now but maybe there is a buffer for fgetc

Comment: Even so, system calls are slow next to local code. Have you not even tested the speed for yourself?

Comment: I'm not gonna do it, I just realize that for every few calls to fgetc (to get a word), the program go through an array of 300.000+ strings linearly.
So fgetc is not the big problem.

Answer (score 4):

In general, it's impossible to answer performance questions without knowing the details of the platform and the exact code you want to compare. However, in this case, buffering the file contents in an array is likely to be much faster on most platforms.

For one, disk is orders of magnitude slower than main memory.

And even if your OS (or libc) caches the data in RAM, `fgetc` still performs a system call to get it, which is likely much slower than a simple memory read.

Also because of the relative slowness of system calls, use `fread` instead of `fgetc` to read a block of bytes in a single call.

Comment: `fread` reads bytes, which are pretty much equivalent to `char`s ([citation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215445/are-there-machines-where-sizeofchar-1-or-at-least-char-bit-8)).

Comment: `fgetc` still does buffering, there aren't any more system calls involved than if you'd do an `fread`.

Comment: Can I just replace the calls to fgetc with fread and cast the result ?

Comment: @FUZxxl Not necessarily -- I can't find this requirement in the standard. Even if it buffers, anecdotally [`fgetc` still turns out to be slower](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225014/why-fgetc-too-slow).

Comment: @Spooky No, use `fread` to read the data straight into your array. You may need a cast.

Comment: @Thomas That's why you should use `getc` if possible, but still, glibc is braindead and doesn't implement that as a macro.

Comment: @Thomas See ISO 9899:2011 §7.21.3 “(...) When a stream is *fully buffered*,
characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a buffer is filled. (...)” This applies to all stdio functions, including `fgetc` and `fread`. On all but the most exotic platforms, streams are buffered by default although the standard leaves that open.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, one `fread` is faster than a series of `fgetc` calls, but `getc` calls are often still as fast as manually keeping track of another layer of buffering and often make for easier code. When speed is needed, consider `getc_unlocked()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should at least use some form of buffering and not read a character at a time to fill the buffer or array.

Better use `fread()` to fill a buffer/array, or you might even look into memory mapping (`mmap`), to avoid copyiing data from the disk cache in kernel mode to a buffer in user mode if you want slightly more performance (since your question is tagged `performance` too). Although, for a single read pass, your harddisk will certainly be the botlleneck.

If you only need to read the data once, `fread()` with buffer(s) might be the way to go.